# flex: assigning id to primitives

Tags: apache-flex, graphics, flex4, primitive

I have created a few flex primitives on screen via action script. Now based on business logic, I need to make changes to some of these primitives such as: changing thickness, direction of arrowhead etc

One thought was to assign id's to these primitives as they are built- how do I do that?

e.g. I get a line built as below

```
var myShape:Shape=new Shape();    
myShape.graphics.lineStyle(thickness,color);    
myShape.graphics.moveTo(XFrom,YFrom);    
myShape.graphics.lineTo(XTo,YTo);
```

If, based on some condition, I want to change the color/ thickness of above, how do i reference this line above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a more easier approach

Basically instead of drawing the primitives directly, assigned the draw to a shape function which will return a Shape object.

Now the primitive line has a easy handler to change properties. let me know if you need  more specific details on how to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

It'd imagine this is done within a component of some sort.  All UIComponents have a [lifecycle](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html) which you want to adhere to.  You can override several functions to get the kind of functionality you want.  Like this:

```
private var _shape:Shape;

override protected function createChildren():void
{
   super.createChildren();
   if(!this._shape)
   {
      this._shape = new Shape();
      addChild(this._shape);
   }

}

override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
{
   super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

   this._shape.graphics.lineStyle(thickness,color);    
   this._shape.graphics.moveTo(XFrom,YFrom);    
   this._shape.graphics.lineTo(XTo,YTo);
}
```

And if you want it to run when you data changes, you should look into `invalidateDisplayList` which you would call after whatever data has changed and it would run the updateDisplayList function on the next frame.